# How to change Data Model directory to class library in .net Core2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

For one of my project which has .net Core 2.0 framework with MVC I want to implement Onion layer architecture to my project. My main issue is that I want to implement EF and Data model to particular class library.But whenever I tries to scaffold it creates under my Web Application. I want to know why it creates by default under Models folder and is that possible to provide path for data model under different class library, if yes how and if no why ?

Comment: Have you tried using the -o option to create class at another location ... also probably coz you are scaffolding under the context of the web app ... AFAIK EFcore cannot run from an assembly’s context ...

Comment: Yes I have tried that , once I created model in other library it shows an error that useSqlserver not found

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue:-
Step 1:- Open Class library and right click on dependency add these 2 package using nuget
 A. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
 B. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Step 2:- Open Package Manager Console, Select Default Project as your class library, and then execute below command

*Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Your Instance Name;User ID=sa;Password=test@123" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models*